# How to generate ACCESS TOKEN using OAuth2 and set limit and refresh it after time limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, nsurlsession

I am creating an app where I have to generate ACCESS TOKEN using oauth2.0 in the app with expire time of 3 mins and I have refresh the access token once it is expired.I am using objective c and nsurlsesions. Can some please help to solve this. 
Thanks for quick response.

Comment: See this https://github.com/p2/OAuth2

Comment: Show attempts, include code, explain where your program doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I dont know swift I am in to ios,and we need to create access token,Can you give any example objective c

Comment: @marekful I dont have any idea about Oauth2 show i dont have any code if you any in objective let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow either of this two links:

OAuth2 via AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager

OAuth2: https://github.com/p2/OAuth2

It includes everything you need.

Comment: thanks for your quick response,https://github.com/p2/OAuth2 this is in swift but I am using objective c,afnetworking In my case am not sending any password i am getting email from gmail thats it.

Comment: Then, you should get Access Token via Google APIs itself.
Check this: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication
Hope it helps

Comment: the link doesnot have any ios code

Comment: I shared the link just to get idea that you can get the access token via google apis when you login via gmail. FYI, you will get token int he response of successful login.

Comment: I would suggest you to update your query with "How to get token with google login" You will get quick responses.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in check 4th point